# How to define multiple ui-views in ui router in webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

how to define multiple views in UI router using Webpack

**My example.component.js file**

```
import exampleHtml from './example.html';
import headerHtml from '../view/header.html';

let exampleComponent = {
    template: exampleHtml,
    controllerAs: 'example',
    controller: function(exampleService) {
        const vm = this;
        vm.title = exampleService.title();
        //   alert('hi');
    }

}

export default exampleComponent;
```

**My example.module**

```
import angular from 'angular';
import routing from './example.route';
import component from './example.component';
import service from './example.service';

angular
  .module('example', [])
  .component('example', component)
  .factory('exampleService', service)
  .config(routing);
```

My example.route

```
function exampleRoutes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/example');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/example');

    $stateProvider
        .state('example', {
            url: '/example',
            component: 'example'
        })
}

export default exampleRoutes;
```

basically i found a way to define route for one view but i want to load multiple views in routes using Ui router

**for example: in my route.js**

```
    $stateProvider
        .state('example', {
            url: '/example',
            views: {
                'header_part': { templateUrl: '../view/header.html' },
                '': { templateUrl: '../view/header.html' },
                'foot_part': { templateUrl: '../view/header.html' }
            },
            component: 'example'
        })
}
```

but it produce error can"t able to load header.html error

i forked from this rep https://github.com/KarlDoyle/angular-es6-webpack-starter

Answer (score 0):

You can use components in multiple views like this [enter link description here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component#named-viewsview-targeting)